# How to copy image with an empty area in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have two 600x600 pictures I need to merge together.

First picture is filled with some background graphics.

Second picture contains one small object positioned in the right spot where it should be on the merged image. The rest of the second picture is transparent.

I want to copy object from the second picture and put it on the first picture with preserving its exact position. When I select the whole 600x600 area of the second picture (ctrl+a), copy and paste it - the object is getting centered as transparent space around it is getting removed (and not copied).

I need to either copy transparent area around it or make it remain at the exact same position after pasting. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not a photoshop user, but is there an add file to layer(s)?  You'd basically want to open one of the files as a layer (or set of layers) of the second file.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm not a photoshop user either. I don't see such option at first glance... Something like that would perfect though, as I have whole bunch of images I need to add, not just one. Also my images are not in photoshop format, just some PNGs.

Comment: Wait, Gimp has a leg up on photoshop in something?  In Gimp it's File->Open as Layers... and works with both an already opened file (which becomes the background) or by opening multiple files at once (the order is determined by some form of sorting).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the windows of both files next to eachother so you can drag and drop the layer from the layer palette to the working area of you destination file.

The clue is to hold down shift before dropping the layer, the original placement will be preserved. This work also when selecting and dragging multiple layers.

Answer (score 0):

I found File > Place option in CS4, which places single image as a layer. I wish it could open a whole bunch of files at once though, but if there is no better solution then I would go with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to copy a part of one layerd PSD to a new one that was used as a sprite for a website. Each tile of the sprite was bigger than the part I copied. So it was cropped. So I created a PSD with the size I wanted but, of course, the tiles were not at the correct position.
I ended up with the following:

1. I set guidelines to how big the tiles should be in the original PSD.
2. I marked the top right part and filled it with black.
3. I marked the top left part and filled it with black.
4. I marked the whole part and since I had the black spots, the correct size was pasted into the sprite tile.
5. Of course, I deleted the black parts in the new PSD so it became "empty" again

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a pretty simple way.

1) Select the area you want to copy.

2) Crop the entire PSD down to that selection

3) Save your file

4) Undo the crop